# constructor.function(constructor) How do you pass an object of the same class to a function?

Tags: c++

So, I just got out of an exam and the final question had a question that required you to find the find whether two circles overlapped given their centerpoints (x,y) and radii.  You were then supposed to call the function using the constructors for the circles and you functions like

`c1.overlaps(c2);`.

I'm not sure how you would pass the values for both c1 and c2 into the function.  Looking at some other code just now it seems like my function declaration should have started with

`void overlaps(Circle &a)`

The argument `Circle &a` would reference `Circle c2` from above but I don't know how `Circle c1` and its valued would be passed in.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Circle
{
    private:
        double x, y, radius;
    public:
        Circle(double &x, double &y, double &radius);
        {
            void overlaps(this);
        }
};

void overlaps(this)
{
    this -> c2;
    double x3 = c2.x;
    double y3 = c2.y;
    double rad3 = c2.radius;
    double z = pow(x3-x,2) + pow(y3-y,2);
    double r = sqrt(z);
    if(c2.radius + radius > r)
        cout<<"The circles overlap.\n";
    else
        cout<<"The circles do not overlap\n";
};

int main()
{
    double x1, x2, y1, y2, rad1, rad2;
    cin>>x1>>y1>>rad1;
    cin>>x2>>y2>>rad2;
    Circle c1 = new Circle(x1, y1, rad1);
    Circle c2 = new Circle(x2, y2, rad2);
    c1.overlaps(c2);
}
```

Comment: This is an attempt to create a member function, but not a very good one. Please read the relevant chapter in your C++ book before continuing!

Comment: In the example you've given, overlaps is a member function of Circle. As such, you only need to pass the second circle to the first. The overlaps function already has access to the data of the first.

Comment: `Circle c1 = new Circle(x1, y1, rad1);` - This isn't Java and that won't work. Again, a book is probably the best remedy.

Comment: You want `bool Circle::overlaps(const Circle &a) const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you didn't write the above code in your exam :)

In essence, function `void overlaps(Circle &a)` should be a member function in class `Circle`.

As you mentioned in your question, when calling `c1.overlaps(c2)`, the explicit argument `a` would be used as a reference to variable `c2`.

And as you **didn't** mention in your question, when calling `c1.overlaps(c2)`, the implicit argument `*this` would be used as a reference to variable `c1` (though you wouldn't have to explicitly use it).

So you should basically define class `Circle` as follows:

```
class Circle
{
private:
    double x, y, radius;
public:
    Circle(double x, double y, double radius);
    bool overlaps(const Circle& a) const;
};
```

Then, you should implement function `overlaps` as follows:

```
bool Circle::overlaps(const Circle& a) const
{
    double z = pow(a.x-x,2) + pow(a.y-y,2);
    double r = sqrt(z);
    return a.radius + radius > r;
};
```

Finally, in function `main`, you can call function `overlaps` as follows:

```
int main()
{
    double x1, x2, y1, y2, rad1, rad2;
    cin>>x1>>y1>>rad1;
    cin>>x2>>y2>>rad2;
    Circle c1 = new Circle(x1, y1, rad1);
    Circle c2 = new Circle(x2, y2, rad2);
    if (c1.overlaps(c2))
        cout<<"The circles overlap.\n";
    else
        cout<<"The circles do not overlap\n";
}
```